# How to localize IOS usage description in `app.json` in an Expo-managed workflow?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I want to localize the usage descriptions in the `ios.infoPlist` key of the `app.json` file.  For example:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "infoPlist": {
       "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to do something",
       "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "This app accesses the library to do something"
    }
 }
```

I know that, if my project was ejected, I could go into the `ios` files and add `InfoPlist.strings`.

But in an Expo managed workflow, how can this be done?

Answer (score 15):

As per the Expo.io documentation, usage strings can be localized by providing translations for the system permissions.

In the `app.json`, add a `locales` key under the `expo` key:

```
"locales" : {
    "fr": "./locales/ios/fr.json"
}
```

and in `fr.json`, add the localized strings:

```
{
  "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Cette app utilise la caméra pour lire les codes-barres et pour ajouter des images.",
  "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Cette app utilise la photothèque pour ajouter des images"
}
```

This is detailed in the Expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/distribution/app-stores/)

Answer (score 0):

**2023 update**

We need to set `ios.infoPlist.CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations: true` and update `app.json` like this

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true
      }
    },
    "locales": {
      "fr": "./locales/ios/fr.json"
    }
  }
}
```

See the documentation to [translate application metadata](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#translating-app-metadata)